# How to use Google Forms in Android

Tags: java, android, android-webview, google-docs, google-forms

I'm using `WebView` to call a form from Google docs in Android. When I run it on my emulator and phone, all the `CheckBox`es can't be clicked. Please help. I hope you can figure it out. Thank you.

Here's my activity class

```
package com.example.nevigrof.ymuc;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class SurveyForm extends Activity {
    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
        }
    }
    WebView webview;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_survey_form);

        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        openURL();
    }

    private void openURL() {
        webview.loadUrl("thegoogleformiwanttobrowse");

    webview.requestFocus();

    }
}
```

Here's my layout xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.nevigrof.ymuc.SurveyForm">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use request focus to be able to click inside the webview.

```
webview.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps, you can try:

add `android:focusable="true"`in your Webview layout

add `Webview.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN|View.FOCUS_UP);`

EDIT: If two solutions are still not working, then try:

```
webview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:                     
                if (!v.hasFocus()) {
                    v.requestFocus();
                }
                break;
        }               
        return false;
    }
});
```

or

```
webview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            v.requestFocusFromTouch();  
            break;
    }               
    return false;
}
});
```

Comment: i did it awhile ago sir but still its not clickable

Comment: Thank you sir but I didn't understand it, where will i put this code, i inserted it on my codes but it gives me errors.

Answer (score 1):

You should enable javascript in your webview:

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: thank you sir, That was my error, thank you again sir for reminding. it helps a lot.

Comment: Done sir but it says Once I earn 15 reputation my  votes will be displayed. maybe bcoz i'm only a new user.

Comment: One more thing sir, I used  String webUrl = webview.getUrl(); so I can toast the URL and it worked, the facebook URL displayed in toast message but when I log in there's no URL toast. Gusto ko po sana ma toast lahat ng URL na pinapasukan ko. Any suggestion sir?

Comment: I'd suggest posting a new question. Please add the relevant code too.